# Replace deprecated `SecTrustGetCertificateAtIndex` in iOS 15?

Tags: ios, swift, ssl, ios15

I'm getting a deprecation warning in `iOS 15` SDK, but the suggested replacement is not a one-to-one replacement. This is what I have for evaluating the SSL trust chain:

```
func valid(_ trust: SecTrust, forHost host: String) -> Bool {
    guard valid(trust, for: [SecPolicyCreateSSL(true, nil)]),
        valid(trust, for: [SecPolicyCreateSSL(true, host as CFString)]) else {
            return false
    }

    let serverCertificatesData = Set(
        (0..<SecTrustGetCertificateCount(trust))
            .compactMap { SecTrustGetCertificateAtIndex(trust, $0) }
            .map { SecCertificateCopyData($0) as Data }
    )

    let pinnedCertificatesData = Set(
        certificates.map { SecCertificateCopyData($0) as Data }
    )

    return !serverCertificatesData.isDisjoint(with: pinnedCertificatesData)
}
```

The warning I get in Xcode 13 beta is:

```
'SecTrustGetCertificateAtIndex' was deprecated in iOS 15.0: renamed to 'SecTrustCopyCertificateChain(_:)'. 
Use 'SecTrustCopyCertificateChain(_:)' instead.
```

However, `SecTrustGetCertificateAtIndex` ([docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1395987-sectrustgetcertificateatindex?language=objc)) returns `SecCertificate` where `SecTrustCopyCertificateChain` ([docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/3747134-sectrustcopycertificatechain?changes=latest_7_7__1)) returns a `CFArray`. How can this properly be updated in the usage I provided?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[iOS 14.5 => iOS 15 SDK Diff](http://codeworkshop.net/objc-diff/sdkdiffs/ios/15.0/Security.html) indicates that the only additions are these (**as of Xcode 13 Beta 1**)

```
SecBase.h
Added errSecInvalidCRLAuthority
Added errSecInvalidTupleCredentials
Added errSecCertificateDuplicateExtension

SecTrust.h
Added SecTrustCopyCertificateChain()
```

They didn't add any new sibling type to `SecCertificate`. As you already noted that it returns a `CFArray`.

```
func SecTrustCopyCertificateChain(_ trust: SecTrust) -> CFArray?
```

So for this part of your code -

```
let serverCertificatesData = Set(
    (0..<SecTrustGetCertificateCount(trust))
        .compactMap { SecTrustGetCertificateAtIndex(trust, $0) }
        .map { SecCertificateCopyData($0) as Data }
)
```

It seems worth a try that `SecTrustCopyCertificateChain` might return a `CFArray` of `SecCertificate` instances? Unfortunately I can't debug this right now.

Maybe try something like this -

```
if let certificates = SecTrustCopyCertificateChain(trust) as? [SecCertificate] {
    let serverCertificatesData = Set(
        certificates.map { SecCertificateCopyData($0) as Data }
    )
}
```

Comment: You're right the `CFArray` was indeed `[SecCertificate]`. Thank you!!